# Why do we need ASP.NET Impersonation: Enabled on IIS 6.0 for default websites?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

Why would we need to enable, IIS Authentication settings for Default Web Sit ?

ASP.NET Impersonation: Enabled
Windows Authentication: Enabled

IIS 6.0 or IIS 7

Comment: It was the legacy of good old Windows days, where enterprises use Windows based user system for certain applications. Now you can walk away without that, as OAuth based authentication/authorization can take over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When enabling the Asp.net impersonation on the IIS server, the client identity could access the windows resource of the server-side with the windows account of the server-side. this is out-dated technology, there is no need to care much about it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/134ec8tc(v=vs.100)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/aspnet/implement-impersonation
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thank you Abraham. It should be fine if we disable it correct